# Running Ubuntu 16.04LTS hangs reboot not shutdown

Tags: reboot

I see that others on here are having this issue when rebooting and shutting down but on my desktop, the hang only happens when restarting/rebooting the computer. It shuts down as it should. When it does hang the mobo shows cpu error on the led. I thought it may be a hardware issue but everything seems to be in order after checking the cpu seating. The computer runs great other than the rebooting issue. I figured it had to be the OS. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: when does it hang?